# Why the checkID() function is using bufferReader not a bufferWriter in here?

Tags: java, oop, io, console-application, bufferedreader

This is an airline reservation system, so this is the class of the traveler. In this class, we have the function of signing up if the user didn't have an account already. However, in this example, it is using a buffered reader that checks the id of the traveler who is still signing up. isn't it supposed to use buffer writer to write the traveler's ID into the CSV file? Please correct me and explain it in deep detail. thanks!

```
public  void signUp(String filepath) throws IOException {
    int check = 0;
    String path = filepath;
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(path, true);
    BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(br);
    
    Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Enter your name");
    String name = i.next();
    
    System.out.println("Enter your password");
    String password = i.next();

    int travellerID = (int)(Math.random()*90000 + 100000);

    check = checkID(travellerID);
    while(check==1) {
        int temp = (int)(Math.random()*90000 + 100000);
        travellerID = temp;
        check = checkID(travellerID);
    }
    
    pw.println(name+","+password+","+travellerID);

    pw.println(name+","+password);
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();

    System.out.println("Congratulations, you have signed up as a passenger!");
    System.out.printf("Your ID is %d \n", travellerID);
    
}
public int checkID(int ID) throws IOException {
    String passengerID = String.valueOf(ID);
    int check = 0;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("publishedFlights.csv"));
    String line;
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
        String[] values = line.split(",");
        if(values[2].contentEquals(passengerID)) {
            check = 1;
        }
    }
    return check;
}
```

Comment: I mean, it's pretty clear that _in addition to_ writing the traveler's ID into the csv file, it is also checking an ID against a (possibly different) CSV that's already there.

Comment: I am still new to coding, so can you please clarify?

Comment: Hard to say with out all the code but my guess would be: How does the application know that a traveler has already previously signed up? It uses the `checkID()` method. If the credentials can't be found then the `signUp()` method is used which also utilizes the `checkID()` method to see if the randomly generated travellerID has already been previously issued in which case it generates yet another ID until one can not be found in file. This is the way the application guaranties unique ID's for everyone that signs up.